# How do I substitute the word under cursor in vim script?

Tags: vim

After getting the current word with `expand("<cWORD>")` and processing the result string, I'm trying to replace the current word with it.

How can I do this?

***EDIT*** Source added. I wrote it in python.

```
cur_word = vim.eval('expand("<cWORD>")')
parts = cur_word.split('.')
if parts:
    obj, accesses = parts[0], parts[1:]
    result = obj + ''.join("['%s']"%a for a in accesses)
    # how do I replace the current word with result?
```

Comment: Huh. You try to replace the current word with itself? Care to give an example?

Comment: @sehe I mean saving it back after processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the python interface for Vim, you can execute normal mode command, in your case,

```
  vim.command("normal BcW%s" % result)
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Suggest use `ciW`.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

It looks like you wanted this:

```
viW
:s/\%V\.\(\w\+\)\%V/\="['" . submatch(1) . "']"/g
```

E.g., for the following text, curosr on the second line:

```
x = a.get.property;
x = a.git.another.property;   # cursor on the first letter 'e'
```

The result will be

```
x = a.get.property;
x = a['git']['another']['property'];
```

---

You probably wanted you

1. *yank one word*, then
2. *move the cursor* (which you don't mention)
3. _replace the word under cursor by previously yanked word?

That would be

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>
     (move cursor around)
     <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>W</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

So e.g.:

```
 the lazy cow mooned over the racy hump
 cursor here:   ----> +
```

Now, doing <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> (yank inner WORD), <kbd>F</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> (back to:)

```
 the lazy cow mooned over the racy hump
  --> +
```

Now, <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>W</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> replaces current WORD:

```
 the over cow mooned over the racy hump
    --> +
```

Comment: just replaced your y with a v. and +1 because this is correct.

Comment: No, I get the content of the word under cursor and do something with it(eg. add a trailing "X"), then replace the word under cursor with that changed content. I know how to do this in command mode, but I have no idea how to do this in a function.

Comment: Well, you _could_ use `py pos = w.cursor` (gets a tuple (row, col)) and go from there (you can probably edit the buffer, or you'd do vimscript like `call setline(".", "blabla")`))

Comment: The `substitute` command you wrote is very concise, can you tell me what's the meaning of those `%V` in the regex part?

Comment: @Satoru.Logic they specify that the match should be within the (last) visual selection. See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#//%V